# Turn list of dictionaries that share column value to pandas multiindex dataframe with keys as columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, multi-index

I have a df with a `wallet` column (which I want to use as the index and a `positions_rewards` column, which is the main target of this question.

Each row in `positions_rewards` is a list of dictionaries (each row has a different amount of dictionaries within their list).

I want to create a `multiindex df` with `wallet` as the `index`, with columns being the `keys`shared amongst all dictionaries (`position` and `position_rewards`).

Basically, each wallet has many positions and corresponding position rewards for each position.

```
                   wallet                  amount  positions_rewards
0  0x00000000000000000000                       0  [{'position': 'LUSD', 'position_rewards': '0'}, {'position': 'ALCX', 'position_rewards': '1000'}]
1  0x000566b53e028d21e104         719082156191632  [{'position': 'LUSD', 'position_rewards': '0'}, {'position': 'ALCX', 'position_rewards': '420'}]
2  0xb72ca7ee0aa8ad85a4ff  4656542682597557130970  [{'position': 'SUSHI_LP', 'position_rewards': 1200}]
3  0x81f01fed84a5bb03813a   777565117641038730248  [{'position': 'SUSHI_LP', 'position_rewards': 300}, {'position': 'UNI_LP', 'position_rewards': 30000}]
4  0x3726a511f7ff6a417e05  1566258882202552609066  [{'position': 'ALCX', 'position_rewards': 2000}]
```

My code is as follows (just a simple `DataFrame` construction out of a list of nested dictionaries (hence the `position_rewards`column being the only one still with "unexploded" values):

`df = pd.DataFrame(rewards_list)`

Notes:

- Ignore `amount` column.
- Is a better idea to create a `DataFrame` with repeating `wallet` rows and then set that as index (or not) to be able to perform `groupby()`operations? My preference is multiindex for now, since I will append other data on that wallet index. So I don't want to have repeating `wallet`rows since it will be harder to merge `dfs`on that instead of on a `df`with unique indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df = df.drop(columns="amount").explode("positions_rewards")
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop("positions_rewards").apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                   wallet  position position_rewards
0  0x00000000000000000000      LUSD                0
0  0x00000000000000000000      ALCX             1000
1  0x000566b53e028d21e104      LUSD                0
1  0x000566b53e028d21e104      ALCX              420
2  0xb72ca7ee0aa8ad85a4ff  SUSHI_LP             1200
3  0x81f01fed84a5bb03813a  SUSHI_LP              300
3  0x81f01fed84a5bb03813a    UNI_LP            30000
4  0x3726a511f7ff6a417e05      ALCX             2000
```

---

If I understand you correctly, you can use `df.pivot` afterwards to obtain your dataframe:

```py
print(
    df.pivot(
        index="wallet",
        columns="position",
        values="position_rewards",
    ).fillna(0)
)
```

Prints:

```
position                ALCX LUSD  SUSHI_LP  UNI_LP
wallet                                             
0x00000000000000000000  1000    0         0       0
0x000566b53e028d21e104   420    0         0       0
0x3726a511f7ff6a417e05  2000    0         0       0
0x81f01fed84a5bb03813a     0    0       300   30000
0xb72ca7ee0aa8ad85a4ff     0    0      1200       0
```

Comment: This is wonderful. Although it does not create a multiindex df, as I requested in the question, I can certainly try to make one out of the result of your answer. (which is the alternative to what I proposed in the question). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @LuizScheuer I updated the answer with `df.pivot` (I hope that's what you meant)

Comment: Your answers are great! Actually, using `df.pivot()` outputs the other possible `DataFrame`structure I was thinking of having. `df.pivot()`, in this case, to answer your question, does not represent what I meant. What I meant in itially was building a multiindex `df` (where you'd see each wallet written only once), but with the same column structure as your initial repply/solution. That is, instead of having LUSD, ALCX, etc as columns, still have positions and position_rewards as columns but each row (wallet) with multiple rows for the position and position_rewards columns (hence, multiindex).